Mysql2 Error when lost connection, it don't reconnect
I develop in nodejs (expressjs) with mysql2. When I close or restart mysql server my application thorws error and nodemon crashes and don't reconnect to mysql server. I want to reconnect every 5 minute.
This is my code:
const mysql = require('mysql2');

let db;

const dbConfig = {
  host: HOST_DB,
  user: USER_DB,
  password: PASSWORD_DB,
  database: DATABASE_NAME,
  port: PORT_DB,
};

function handleDisconnect() {

  db = mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);

  db.connect(error => {
    if (error) {
      console.error('Error connecting to the database:', error);
      setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 300000);
    }
  });

  db.on('error', error => {
    console.error('Database error:', error);
    if (error.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
      console.log('Attempting to reconnect to the database...');
      handleDisconnect();
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  });

}
handleDisconnect()

db = mysql.createConnection(dbConfig);

Error:
node:events:497
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\otp\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:117:31)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:338:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection._notifyError (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\otp\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:252:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\otp\server\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:123:12)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:519:28)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:338:12) {
  fatal: true,
  code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
}

Node.js v20.15.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

I want to reconnect to mysql server every 5 minute. Then my backend server can work without having me to shut it down and restart it.

Maybe consider using the Pool so the library can maintain the connections?

You can use a combination of connection pooling and a reconnect mechanism
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const dbConfig = {
  host: HOST_DB,
  user: USER_DB,
  password: PASSWORD_DB,
  database: DATABASE_NAME,
  port: PORT_DB,
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  queueLimit: 0
};

let pool;

function createPool() {
  pool = mysql.createPool(dbConfig);

  pool.on('connection', function (connection) {
    console.log('Database connection established');
  });

  pool.on('error', function (err) {
    console.error('Database error:', err);
    if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST' || err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED' || err.code === 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR') {
      console.log('Attempting to reconnect to the database in 5 minutes...');
      setTimeout(createPool, 300000); // 5 minutes
    } else {
      throw err;
    }
  });

  // This is an example query to test the connection
  pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error connecting to the database:', err);
      setTimeout(createPool, 300000); // 5 minutes
    } else {
      console.log('Connected to the database');
      if (connection) connection.release();
    }
  });
}

createPool();

module.exports = pool;

